# Regexp_Substr issue

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have to parse a notes field with some pretty crummy characters in it which I need to extract a date from some internal jargon.

Basically the fields Look like this, this being 4 different notes I'd want to pull just the date out of:

```
Ltr Cert Expires  ****01/15/17***
Ltr Cert Expires  ***01/5/2010***
Ltr Cert Expires  **01/10/11***
Ltr Cert Expires  *******01/15/01***
```

I'm not super familiar with regexp_substr but I poked around on here for a bit and didn't see many examples which met what I was looking for.

Any ideas? And maybe some suggested reading on Regexp for Oracle? I'm pretty new to this feature and the codes are a little baffling at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a quite self-explanatory way.

It looks for a sequence of one or two digits (`[0-9]{1,2}`), followed by a '/' (`\/`), and so on.

This could be re-written in many different, more compact or more sharp ways, for example to check that the content really represents a date, but if you assume that every row (as for your sample data) always contains exactly one date, in one of the formats of the sample data, this can be enough:

```
with test(t) as (
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  ****01/15/17***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  ***01/5/2010***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  **01/10/11***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  *******01/15/01***' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(t, '[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}')
from test
```

gives:

```
01/15/17
01/5/2010
01/10/11
01/15/01
```

Just to give an example of a different approach, on this data the following gives the same result:

```
regexp_substr(t, '([^\*]+)', 1, 2)
```

This searches for a sequence of at least one character different from `'*'`, but returns the second occurrence (the fourth parameter with value `2`). The first occurrence is whatever you have before the first `'*'`, thus the second occurrence is the part of the string between the first and the second sequence of `'*'`s.

In this case, this would return whatever string you have, no matter if it's a date or not.

This

```
with test(t) as (
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  ****01/15/17***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  ***01/5/2010***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  **01/10/11***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  *******01/15/01***' from dual union all
    select 'Ltr Cert Expires  *******Not a date, but ...***' from dual    
)
select regexp_substr(t, '[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2,4}') as str1,
       regexp_substr(t, '([^\*]+)', 1, 2) as str2
from test
```

gives :

```
STR1       STR2
---------- ------------------------------
01/15/17   01/15/17
01/5/2010  01/5/2010
01/10/11   01/10/11
01/15/01   01/15/01
           Not a date, but ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I kept getting lost trying to figure out how to search by characters, maybe finding what comes after the stars and I hadn't really considered just searching for the numbers and matching 1 and 2 occurrences.

Comment: @JordanHaymond: just showed a different way, just for explanation